# Tengo este proyecto, pero no se como hacer que el html muestre el resultado del id="cuadrotexto"

Tags: javascript, html5, nodejs

Tengo este proyecto, pero no se como hacer que el html muestre el resultado del id="cuadrotexto"

consiste en que al darle al botón, rellene en el imput los datos de la fecha del servidor, pero no termino de saber como hacerlo
html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <title>index</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="actualizarhora()">BOTÓN</button>
    <input type="text" id="cuadrotexto" />
    <script src="servidor.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

y el script

```
const http = require('http');
 
const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;
 
const fs = require('fs').promises;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + "/index.html")
      .then(contents => {
          res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
          res.writeHead(200);
          res.end(contents);
        })
;});

function actualizarhora() {
  var cuadrotexto = document.getElementById("cuadrotexto");
  //console.log(cuadrotexto.value);
  cuadrotexto.value = '{"time":"'+new Date().toJSON()+'"}';
};

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`El servidor se está ejecutando en http://${hostname}:${port}/index.html`);
});
```